# How to merge matrix and array of different size in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have one matrix of size 12 and array of size 4 as given below:

```
A=[23,45,1;4,6,7;9,5,0;145,65,32];                 
B=[3,2,4,6];
```

I want new array `C` as

```
C=[23,45,1,4,6,7,9,5,0,145,65,32,3,2,4,6];
```

I did following :

```
A=[23,45,1;4,6,7;9,5,0;145,65,32];                 
B=[3,2,4,6]; 
A=reshape(A',12,1);            
B=B(:);       
C=[A B];
```

But its giving error :

```
Error using ==> horzcat      
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = A(:);            
B = B(:);       
C = [A; B];
```

Note the difference between [A B] or [A, B] and [A; B].